# How to get dob,gender,email from linkedin api

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, parsing, linkedin-api

How to get dob,gender,email from linkedin api.

Below function that is used for get info:

```
 function onLinkedInAuth() {
        IN.API.Profile("me")
       .fields(["firstName", "lastName", "headline", "email-address", "date-of-birth"])
       .result(function (me) {
           /// alert(m);
           var id = me.values[0].id;
           var fname = me.values[0].firstName;
           var lname = me.values[0].lastName;
           var email = me.values[0].pemail;
           var gender = me.values[0].gender;
           alert(me.values[0].dateofbirth);
           alert(fname + ' ' + lname + ',' + email + ',' + gender);
           // AJAX call to pass back id to your server
       });
    }
```

Its always return blank string of dob and email.

Comment: you can use this api to get gender http://api.namsor.com/onomastics/api/json/gendre/John/Smith

Answer (score 0):

Date-of-birth is only available for the user that is authenticated to the application, not connections.

Your application was most likely migrated to member permissions which does not allow querying of date-of-birth of connections.